# How to avoid repeating same block of formula n times

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

### Explanation

I found my issue to be common for things that I'm working on right now and that I have done in the past.

I'm writing an Excel formula that for a given input from column `Lookup value` will scan 10 different Excel files for a value to be returned using `MATCH` and `INDEX` functions.

```
    [A]              [B]
Lookup value    Returned value
    123              val
```

Column `Returned value` has a following formula (sketch):

```
=IFNA(
  INDEX('[File1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$B;MATCH(A2;'[File1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B:$B;0);1);
  INDEX('[File1.xlsx]Sheet2'!$A:$B;MATCH(A2;'[File1.xlsx]Sheet2'!$B:$B;0);1)
 )
```

Basic idea for this is to look for a value from the first column in a row where the given value (input) is present in any of two sheets in a file. **And do the exact same thing for 10 times with different file names**.

I'm using `IFNA` function to keep going until a value is found in any file or all files have been processed.

### Question

Without repeating the given sketch 10 times for every file in `File1, ... File10` how could I approach this issue simpler, as of not repeating the code 10 times? The simpler the better.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing it in VBA instead. Then you can easily loop through the files instead, e.g:

```
Function FindValue()

    Dim fileNames
    fileNames = Array("FileName1", "FileName2", "FileName3")


    For i = 1 To UBound(fileNames)
        'Generic code for finding value using fileName(i)
    Next i
End Function
```

Update:

This seems to work for me. Error handling could probably have been done better though. Might need to change behaviour depending on what you want to do if there is no match.

```
Function FindValue(LookupString)

    Dim fileNames
    Dim tempRange
    Dim tempRange3

    fileNames = Array("VBATesting2.xlsm", "VBATesting3.xlsm")
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    For i = 0 To UBound(fileNames)
        tempRange = Workbooks(fileNames(i)).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:B").Find(LookupString).Offset(, 1)
        If tempRange <> "" Then
            FindValue = tempRange
            Exit Function
        Else
            tempRange = Workbooks(fileNames(i)).Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:B").Find(LookupString).Offset(, 1)
            If tempRange <> "" Then
                FindValue = tempRange
                Exit Function
            Else
                FindValue = "No Match"
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    ErrorHandler:
    tempRange = ""
    Resume Next
End Function
```

Comment: Could you provide a working example? I did not tag my question VBA because of my little knowledge of it

Comment: Can the same lookup value occur more than once, and if so will they always be the same, i.e. will it be fine to return the value of the first match (if there is a match)?

Comment: It can occur more than once and yes - it will should return value of the first match if there at least one.